# running windows 7/8 as KVM virtual machine on ubuntu

Tags: windows, kvm-virtualization

I have installed ubuntu alongside windows 7/8 on my machine. Is it possible to run my windows instance as a KVM virtual machine?

Do I have to install windows again in KVM?

Comment: You need specific drivers inside KVM http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/WindowsGuestDrivers/Download_Drivers during installation of a windows system or else the system won't recognise the virtual harddrive. So you presumably need to reinstall it in KVM.

Answer (score 0):

According to [KVM's documentation](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Guest_Support_Status) Windows 7 and 8 are both supported, but may need extra drivers for the virtual disks, depending on what options you use (virtio is advantageous, but often requires drivers).

You **will** have to reinstall Windows again to run it in KVM.